# What is difference between CQL for Cassandra 2.x and CQL for Cassandra 1.2

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

I am new to Cassandra so I have started with current version of CQL(Cassandra 2.x).So I want major difference between  CQL for Cassandra 2.x and CQL for Cassandra 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_intro_c.html (and its differences from http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/about_cql_ref_c.html) the main difference(s) are:

- Lightweight transactions using the IF keyword in INSERT and UPDATE
  statements.
- Initial support for triggers.
- The ALTER TABLE DROP command, which had been removed in the earlier release.
- Column aliases, similar to aliases in RDBMS SQL, in a SELECT statement.
- Indexing of any part, partition key or clustering columns, portion of a compound primary key.
- CQL for Cassandra 2.0 deprecated super columns. Cassandra continues to support apps that query super columns, translating super columns on the fly into CQL constructs and results.
- The ASSUME command has been removed.
- The COPY command supports collections.
- New CQL table attributes: `default_time_to_live`, `memtable_flush_period_in_ms`, `populate_io_cache_on_flush`, `speculative_retry`